# elect data from related tables with duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables.

news

```
id  title   description
```

rubrics

```
id  title   parent_id
```

parent_id is key for id  parent in table rubrics.

And "news_rubriks"

```
id  news_id rubric_id
```

How I can select news which apply to rubrics.id and rubrics.parent_id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply a filter to both the rubrik id and the parent.  Say if you are searching for `1`, then you want `1` in either column.

If so:

```
select n.*
from news n join
     news_rubriks nr
     on nr.news_id = n.id left join
     rubrik r
     on nr.rubrik_id = r.id
where ? in (r.id, r.parent_id)
```